# What does the d:IsControlPart attribute do in Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

In Expression Blend 4 the Simple Styles use the following XML namespace:

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/interactivedesigner/2006
```

It frequently uses an attribute from this namespace called **IsControlPart** which is a boolean.  I've googled extensively and can't find any actual documentation on this attribute.

Comment: To which assembly does that belong?

Comment: It don't think it is part of any assembly.  It doesn't exist at runtime, it's only used for design-time purposes in the Blend IDE.  It uses the Markup Compatibility "Ignorable" attribute to tell the XAML compiler to ignore it.

Comment: Seems like a logical annotation about the object being styled...

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out.

When WPF creates the default templates for its controls, it names some of the elements with the prefix "PART".  For example, with a Slider control, it has two parts, **PART_Track** and **PART_SelectionRange**.  This in itself has nothing to do with Expression Blend.

These parts necessary for the basic functionality of the control.  Most simple controls, like a Button, do not have any parts, so they can be fully customized without having any restrictions.

More complex controls rely on parts being present in order for the code-behind to work properly.  It doesn't care what the control looks like, or where they are in the visual tree, so long as they exist and are of the right type.

In Expression Blend, there is a "Parts" window which is by default a tab alongside the "Project" and "Assets" tabs.  When you are editing a template for a Control, if there are any parts defined for that control it lists them in this Parts window.  It shows a check mark if that part exists in the current template, and if not you can double click on it and Blend will create the element for you.

I am still not sure exactly how the d:IsControlPart attribute works.  I tried making my own custom Control and creating a element with the IsControlPart tag, and then creating a template for that control to see if it would list the part.  It didn't.  So this is still not 100% answered.

Comment: I thought of this connection as well but i am pretty sure that it has *absolutely nothing* to do with `IsControlPart`. Those parts work via the [`TemplatePartAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx) which is set on the control classes, see for example the syntax section of [`ProgressBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx).